# Dynamic API KEY with react native maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm building an app that will make use of react native maps and I'd like to know if there is any way that I can set the Google API key dynamically on runtime. I looked around and I haven't seen anything about it.

My app will be used by a few different clients, each client has its own google api key that is stored in our database, so I'd like to use the clients own key.

Is there any way to do it? I only saw it being set up on the manifest, which I believe is unchangeable.

Thanks!